# JBoss security issue

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jboss

i am ruuning jboos on windows xp , found in the logs some one has deployed web app to jboss which enables him to open socket to my machine.

i don't understand how he could upload such WAR file to the deployment directory of jboss .

any ideas please ?

Comment: Maybe you have an exploitable security bug or misconfiguration in one of the other web application(s) running inside jboss? Or in another server running on the machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attacker may have exploited JMX console default configuration vulnerability (JBoss JIRA JBAS-8954). It is a well known vulnerability, so you should be able to find the remedy.

More on this issue:

- http://www.articlesbase.com/security-articles/exploitation-and-remediation-of-jboss-application-server-default-configuration-vulnerability-1889469.html
- http://goohackle.com/jboss-security-vulnerability-jmx-management-console/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR up to JBoss v4 you could just copy WARs to the deploy directory and let JBoss autodeploy them. Could it be that somebody were able to copy a file there perhaps over a network share?

Next it was possible to deploy web applications using JBoss Management Console - this is accessible over the network, is it opened on your machine? Did you change default user/password?

Comment: yes the jboss management console is open , shall i remove the root wep app ?

Comment: only if you don't need it, otherwise just secure the access